# Coldfusion webservice inserting extra namespaces in SOAP response

Tags: soap, coldfusion

I have a webservice in coldusion which is putting in extra namespaces/nodes in my response. I have tried several ways to get rid of the namespaces but nothing works. Is there a way to remove these namespaces/nodes(
    ) ??

```
<ns1:getInventoryLevelsResponse>
    <getInventoryLevelsReturn>
        <s:Envelope>
            <s:Header/>
            <s:Body>
               ...valid nodes...
             </s:Body>
         </s:Envelope>
     </getInventoryLevelsReturn>
</ns1:getInventoryLevelsResponse>
```

Comment: so, you don't want a soap response?